# What are the benefits of Spring Testing in terms of testing web services?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-test

I am implementing an application that tests web services, and I am wondering if it is worthy to use spring testing.

In my application I call web services and test if the results returned match with the ones expected, so I don't need to inject any DAO.

**Did I miss any other benefits ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you test an external webservice, you don't need spring. You even don't need java as you might as well write good tests with `soapUI`.

Anyhow, if you're testing your own webservice classes, you probably have to mock some services at testing time, and therefore spring testing might help alot.

Comment: I am trying to implement an application that tests web services automatically, i.e given input I call a web service with this request and I check if the response match with the one I expect. I use JUnit to create parametrized tests to do so.

Comment: So then, it is an external webservice that you don't have class conroll off. You will probably have no benefit from spring testing.